# ¿Cómo crear un Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo problemas para crear un array, estoy utilizando el código insertado a continuación:

**Código:**

```js
  var arr_data = [];

  arr_data[0] = 123;
  arr_data[1] = 321;
  arr_data[2] = 765;
  
  var row = {},dat = [];
  
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row.cod = arr_data[i];
    console.log(row);
    dat.push(row);
  
  } 
  console.log('-------------------------------');
  console.log(dat[0]);
  console.log(dat[1]);
  console.log(dat[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Al ejecutar se puede ver que el valor almacenado es solo el último, no comprendo por qué pasa esto ni cómo solucionarlo.

**NOTA:**

La variable `arr_data` refleja un ejemplo sobre los datos que estoy tratando y que me permite formular el problema que tengo.

Comment: row{}, no es un array, es un objeto que es distinto

Comment: estas pusheando una referencia, al actualizar la referencia se actualiza el valor (referenciado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un claro ejemplo de los problemas que surgen cuando se trabaja con referencias a objetos, los objetos (`{}`) son pasados por referencia, no por valor:

```js
row = {'cod': 123}

data = [row, row, row]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}

console.log('--------------------');

// ¿Y si cambiamos el valor de row.cod?
row.cod = 789

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Y eso es exactamente lo que está pasando en tu código, al llegar a la última iteración, `row.cod` toma el valor de `765`. Los tres `push` que has hecho usan el mismo `row` y, por lo tanto, todos tienen el mismo valor:

```
{
  "cod": 765
}
```

Me parece que no necesitas definir una variable como `row` previamente. Podrías simplemente hacer:

```js
var arr_data = [];

arr_data[0] = 123;
arr_data[1] = 321;
arr_data[2] = 765;
  
var dat = [];
  
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  dat.push({'cod': arr_data[i]});
  
} 
  
console.log('-------------------------------');
console.log(dat[0]);
console.log(dat[1]);
console.log(dat[2]);
```

Comment: Gracias Cesar, tu respuesta fue acertada y gracias por la explicación.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr_data = [];

  arr_data[0] = 123;
  arr_data[1] = 321;
  arr_data[2] = 765;

  var dat = new Array();

   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
     var row = {};
    row.cod = arr_data[i];    
     console.log(row);
    dat.push(row);

  } 
  console.log('-------------------------------');
  console.log(dat[0]);
  console.log(dat[1]);
  console.log(dat[2]);
```